# INotifyPropertyChanged: Notify another class

Tags: wpf, data-binding, datagrid, inotifypropertychanged

I have a class (let's call it `MyContainerClass`)that is a container for several other classes (let's call them `ClassA` to `ClassF`). `ClassA` to `ClassF` inherit the same base class (let's call it `MyBaseClass`). In `MyBaseClass` I have an int property with the name `Count`, which  `ClassA` to `ClassF` inherit. I also have an int property with the same name in `MyContainerClass` which is the sum of `ClassA` to `ClassF`.

Then I have a datagrid, and each row has one object of `MyContainerClass`. The columns of the grid show `ClassA` to `ClassF`. The last column in the grid shows a total (that is it is bound the `Count` property of `MyContainerClass`). Now I want that the total in the last column updates as soon as I change the `Count` property in any class in the A-F range. I implemented INotifyPropertyChanged in `MyBaseClass` and it does fire when I change the `Count` property in  `ClassA` to `ClassF`. But the last column in my datagrid remains the same. Any clues?

**EDIT:**
I have created a class diagram. [image]

The getCount() method returns objA.Count+objB.Count+...+objF.Count and is returned by the `Count` property in the `MyContainerClass`. The question is: if I update objA.Count I want the GUI (that is the column in my datagrid) to display the updated sum.

Comment: You say that the datagird remains the same, but does the property itself change? In other words - Did you check to see if the `Count` property in the `MyContainerClass` is updated or not?

Comment: If you could post some XAML and some sourcecode for your classes then it will be easier to diagnose what is going wrong!

Comment: @Blachshma, it is updated. If I check the objects in the debugger I always see the correct numbers. Only the GUI does not update.

Comment: @StephenHolt, I'd have to change a lot of code to create a generic example. But I have created a class diagram. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 4):

Just implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` is not enough for an automatic update. The `MyContainerClass` object needs to "subscribe" to the change notifications of the `MyBaseClass` objects in the other columns. One way you can handle this is by adding a method like the following to the `MyContainerClass`:

```
void SubscribeToCount(MyBaseClass item)
{
    item.PropertyChanged += (s,e) => 
        this.Sum += (e.NewValue - e.OldValue); 
}
```

And you call this method for all the objects in the other columns. (It's not clear from the question but I assume there is a wrapper class that includes instances of `MyClassA-F` and `MyContainerClass`, which you bind the datagrid to a collection of this wrapper class).

Comment: This solved the same problem I was having, where I needed an (initially, calculated) property to notify of changes to a different class. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Okay, here is what I did after staring at Eren's solution for a while: I also implemented the INotifyPropertyChanged for the container class and registered the `PropertyChanged` event for each object.

```
objA.PropertyChanged += updateCount;
objB.PropertyChanged += updateCount;
objC.PropertyChanged += updateCount;
```

...and so on. Then I added the following method

```
private void updateCount(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    OnPropertyChanged("Count");
}
```

Now I have the behavior that I want.

Comment: Great, that's pretty much the kind of solution I would have suggested having now understood your problem! I think you can mark your own answer as the accepted answer can you?

Comment: And instead of _updateCount_ you mean _updateSum_ and instead of `OnPropertyChanged("Count")` you mean `OnPropertyChanged("Sum")`, because a _Sum_ property in `MyContainerClass` just is the better name.