# How to update Progress from state of ObservableCollection<T>?

Tags: c#, mvvm, maui, maui-community-toolkit

I have an `ObservableCollection<T>`, `T` object has nested `ObservableCollection<U>`, `U` class has a `IsCompleted` boolean. How can I collect on my ViewModel the Progress which is the % of completed.

TestPage:

```xml
<ProgressBar Progress="{Binding Progress}" />
```

```cs
class TestViewModel
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    public ObservableCollection<T> _items;
    public double Progress
    {
        get
        {
            return ((double)Items.NestedItems.SelectMany(e => e.NestedItems).Count(s => s.IsCompleted) / (double)Items.Sum(e => e.NestedItems.Count));
        }
    } 

    void Init()
    {
        // load data
    }  
}

class T
{
    public ObservableCollection<U> NestedItems { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<U>();

}

class U :ObservableObjectBase
{
    bool IsCompleted {get;set;}
}
```

So with Progress I am trying to collect the percentage of `IsCompleted` of the nested item.
The problem is Progress is not updated at all.

Comment: The two types are orthogonal... an `ObservableCollection<T>` represents a collection that **might** be updated in future - or it might not: there's no implied _contract_ over temporal affairs here. Whereas `IProgress<T>` represents events being raised through the a one-way passage of time.

Comment: BTW, you're using `ObservableCollection<>` incorrectly in `NestedItems`: you need to ensure it's used only in `readonly` fields (i.e. `get`-only properties) because you're not meant to detach `ObservableCollection<>` instances from their view-model owners. Change it to `public ObservableCollection<U> NestedItems { get; } = new ObservableCollection<U>();`

Comment: DO NOT do this. Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13376328/inotifypropertychanged-notify-another-class , but DO NOT implement it. There are ways to mess up your performance beyond repair, but this is one of the top. You cannot fire event for every single item. When you download a file, do you upgrade the progress for each byte you get? No. You update it every X cycles. Or if you do not have control over the thread that prepares them, you can update it at time intervals. Still thousand times better. You are trying to build a LAG machine. Read how to do it, but do not do it.

Comment: My goal is i have lets say a collectionview with ToDo items and when one item is checked as completed the progress bar would show the % of the completed tasks.

Comment: Use intermediate media instead of directly using ObservableCollection<T>